# RTools Big Data and Visual Studio

Tags: r, visual-studio, microsoft-r

So, I'm working on a big data project which requires importing data into Visual Studio and using Microsoft's R packages, in particular, the RevoScaleR packages. So, this is all well and good. I've written my scripts. What I would like to do is set it up so an end-user (who doesn't know anything about programming or R) can enter a set of parameters/values into my predict() function and see the output on his/her screen through a web interface or GUI/similar.

Any suggestions? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by leveraging Microsoft R Server's Operationalization Features, as this is a general question, please see the guides here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-r/operationalize/quickstart-publish-web-service

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this. I will go through the link you sent.